# Having font issue with VS Code Terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code, macos-mojave, iterm2, powerline

On my Mac OS Mojave, I am using iTerm2 with [powerlevel9k](https://github.com/bhilburn/powerlevel9k) theme.

For the fonts to render well, I am using `SourceCodePro+Powerline+Awesome+Regular` as the font and also added a line `POWERLEVEL9K_MODE='awesome-patched'` to the .zhrc.

The emojis are not rendering well on vs code terminal. So vscode's settings.json, I set `"terminal.integrated.fontFamily": "'SourceCodePro+Powerline+Awesome+Regular',",`. That hasn't fixed the issue. So, I set `"terminal.external.osxExec": "iTerm.app"`. That also doesn't help.

What could be the reason? How can I fix it? How is vs code terminal different from iterm2?

Not sure if this related to the font issue. what ever command I give in VSCode Terminal, is repeating.

- demo >> demozsh: command not found: demo
- echo >> echo
- cd Documents >> cd%

What is the issue I am facing?

Comment: I had same problem. Adding the correct font name fixed it for me:
"terminal.integrated.fontFamily": "'SourceCodePro+Powerline+Awesome Regular'",

Answer (score 0):

**Unicode 11 support**

The width of characters in the terminal now default to the unicode 11 widths. What this means to most people is that emojis will be correctly showing up as wide characters.

from https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_43.md#unicode-11-support possibly fixed in v1.43